# ERROR: Spider error processing - Scrapy error

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm learning how to use Scrapy and tried to apply it to crawl my school directory.

I'm using Scrapy 2.0.0

Whenever I press the command in the cmd (Jupyter)

```
scrapy crawl gettheprof_dict
```

The error appears in the log:

> ERROR: Spider error processing https://bizfaculty.nus.edu.sg/faculty-directory/> (referer: None)

Here is the code in my gettheprof_dict spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class GettheprofDictSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gettheprof_dict'
    allowed_domains = ['bizfaculty.nus.edu.sg']
    start_urls = ['http://bizfaculty.nus.edu.sg/faculty-directory/','http://bizfaculty.nus.edu.sg/faculty-directory/page/2/']

    def parse(self, response):

        print("processing: " + response.url)

        #Extract data using css selectors
        prof_name  = response.css("div.cards-details h4 a::text").extract()
        prof_class = response.css("div.cards-details div span:text").extract()

        prof_department=response.css("div.cards-details div strong::text").extract()

        prof_place = response.css("ul.cards-contact li:nth-child(1) div::text").extract(),
        prof_phone = response.css("ul.cards-contact li:nth-child(2) div::text").extract(),
        prof_email = response.css("ul.cards-contact li:nth-child(3) div::text").extract(),

        row_data=zip(prof_name,prof_class,prof_department,prof_place,prof_phone,prof_email)

        #Making extracted data row wise
        for item in row_data:
            #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
            scraped_info = {
                #key:value
                'page':response.url,
                'Prof_name' : item[0], #item[0] means product in the list and so on, index tells what value to assign
                'Prof_Class' : item[1],
                'Prof_Department' : item[2],
                'Prof_place' : item[3],
                'Prof_phone' : item[4],
                'Prof_email' : item[5],

            }

            #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield scraped_info
```

I have no idea what went wrong. I can access the link easily without any problems.
Any suggestions will be very very helpful. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was not the error that causes my Scrapy idle but my code did a few syntaxes wrong.

```
        prof_class = response.css("div.cards-details div span:text").extract()
```

It should be:

```
        prof_class = response.css("div.cards-details div span::text").extract()
```